C# / WiX - Windows 11 Modern Context Menu Entry
I have an application that can be launched by right-clicking on a file an accessing the context menu entry.
Now on Windows 10 etc this is easy to deploy by installing the below registry keys with my application.
<Component>
    <RegistryKey Root="HKCR" Key="*\shell\mycommand">
        <RegistryValue Action="write" Type="string" Value="My Command Description" />
        <RegistryValue Action="write" Name="Icon" Type="string" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]MyLaunchExe.exe" />
        <RegistryKey Key="command">
            <RegistryValue Action="write" Type="string" Value="&quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]MyLaunchExe.exe&quot; &quot;%1&quot;" />
        </RegistryKey>
    </RegistryKey>
</Component>

Again, this works fine on Windows 11, but it only appears when you click "Show more options" and access the legacy context menu.
Ideally it would like to appear on the modern context menu, similar to how Notepad++ / OneDrive does.
Does anyone know how I can achieve this?
I have spent a lot of time researching this but have no luck, I even went through the hassle of writing a COM component that implemented IShellExtInit & IContextMenu but again I could only get this to show on the legacy context menu.
I have also seen a lot of posts regarding an application called Custom Context Menu to add custom items, this is not suitable for me as I need to deploy the application via an installer.
Any ideas is greatly appreciated. Hopefully this is the correct place to post this question.
